# Word to describe ideology of unfettered belief in rational self-interest

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, philosophy

I'm looking for a word that captures the ideology of believing everything can be traced back to rational self-interest. I know that this is a form of [weak altruism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/altruism-biological/), and that many ideas of economic rationality, capitalism, and Enlightenment/neoliberal ideologies tend to be rooted in this, but I can't place the exact word for it.

In fact, the definition of neoliberalism comes close, in how it is described as a faith in the value of the free-market *in itself*. I am looking for the definition of "faith in the fundamentality of human self-interest *in itself*." A sort of reductionism where cooperation, community, and all those other good things get traced back to self-interest.

This came about in a discussion about neoliberalism. We began to conflate neoliberalism with this idea, which I think has its own word.

Comment: _Psychological egoism_ comes close. "The view that humans are always motivated by self-interest, even in what seem to be acts of altruism." [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_egoism)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about philosophy, not English language.

Comment: "Captures the ideology of"?

Comment: What is a 'fettered belief'?

Comment: You might get a better suggestions at philosophy.SE where they will have lots of specific domain knowledge.

Comment: Machiavellianism comes close, but doesn't seem to include the group-interest part. [Coopetition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coopetition) is a neologism that also attempts to describe this. In economics, it is most commonly known as [rational actors or rational choice theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_choice_theory).

Comment: The OP is asking for "a word" for this type of thinking. @TRomano, "fettered," in this context would mean "moderate," or "conditional."

Comment: TRomano has a good point. The question should read "belief in unfettered rational self-interest"

Comment: Asked this question on philosophy stackexchange, got downvoted and redirected here :).

Comment: Is there any reason why "enlightened self-interest" doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Ayn Rand called it "Objectivism".

Comment: This could be the answer but it would be great if you could explain!

Comment: Sorry, I've never read Ayn Rand. But from what I've heard about her writings, it seems to fit.

Answer (score 1):

From an economic perspective "neoliberalism" certainly is apt; from a psychological perspective, which would precede an economics (or any other) perspective "egoism," as ermanen suggested.

Comment: Could you explain more about why *neoliberalism* is apt?

Comment: EleventhDoctor, I don't understand what you don't understand, you use the term *neoliberal* and *neoliberalism* 4X in the OP, and though the purported purpose of this OP is to identify *a word that captures the ideology of believing everything can be traced back to rational self-interest*, you also claim *the definition of neoliberalism comes close*. I'm left not really understanding what you want, but it seems as if you would like to have a philosophical discussion. Speaking for myself, neoliberalism = economic feudalism. A human self is not merely composed of an ego, but includes family ...

Comment: extended family, clan, tribe, nation, culture, and ultimately, the entire ecosystem along w/the inorganic substrate upon which all else is founded and nourished. What is the definition of *rational* in the term *rational self-interest*? Radical egoism, in the guise of *neoliberal economics* strikes me as anything but rational.

Comment: Apologies @Little-Eva, I didn't pose the question so I am not the OP. However I can see that I should have read the question more carefully! Thank you very much for laying out your thoughts on the matter.

Comment: My apologies @EleventhDoctor, I made an erroneous assumption and failed to refer back to the OP, my bad! To tell you the truth, I do not actually understand what this OP is seeking (for the reasons I addressed to you, mistakenly, in the previous comment), though when I originally answered I thought I did. Oh well. Sorry, again.

Answer (score 1):

Beard's concept of 'economic determinism' is a possibility. Economic determinism holds that ideology is based on the structure of economic relationships, so all ideology in a capitalist economy is purely in one's self interest.